# How to configurate apache kudu with Impala in DC/OS?

Tags: impala, dcos, apache-kudu

We need configurate Kudu master and kudu tablet server in DC/OS. We need
The architecture is similar to that:
[Enter here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4QDV.png)

How configurate the services in DC/OS to scale correctly. We need to have Impala Daemon, kudu Tablet Server and Hadoop Data Node replicated.

Answer (score 1):

All three Impala Daemon, Kudu Server, and Hadoop DataNode are independent so you have to make sure that how much data you need to load into each.

When it comes to Kudu replication:
Tablet Servers and Masters use the Raft Consensus Algorithm, which ensures that as long as more than half the total number of replicas are available, the tablet is available for reads and writes. For instance, if 2 out of 3 replicas or 3 out of 5 replicas are available, the tablet is available.